# How to guarantee logical volumes will fit

Tags: lvm

I am throwing together a script to do lvm actions and I have the following scenario:

```
>blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sdb
2147483648
```

2147483648 / 1024 / 1024 = 2048M

```
>pvs
PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize PFree
/dev/sdb   vg00 lvm2 a--u 2.00g 2.00g

>vgs
VG   #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree
vg00   1   1   0 wz--n- 2.00g 2.00g
```

Now I want to add 2 logical volumes that are both exactly 1 gig. However when I try this:

```
>/sbin/lvcreate -L 1024M -n lv00 vg00 
  Logical volume "lv00" created.

>/sbin/lvcreate -L 1024M -n lv01 vg00
  Volume group "vg00" has insufficient free space (255 extents): 256 required.
```

I get bit because I do not have enough space. Looked up at the blockdev line the raw disk is 2 Gigs.

I note that if I do a pvs or vgs after the first logical volume is create the free space is 1020.00m. I assume because the server needs to use part of the disk for management reasons, i.e. the 5 missing megabytes.

**Is there a way to guarantee how much the system needs so that I can correctly create two disks of the same exact size?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allocate your logical volumes in *extents*. Use `vgdisplay` to ascertain the extent size (known from the "PE Size" field) and specify an appropriate number of extents, that when
doubled does not exceed the "Total PE" of the volume group. This avoids small rounding errors when a size specification like 2-GiB is reduced to a number of extents.